# Add http if necessary to a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the following is a string that is displayed in a jquery confirm box.

```
warningString = "<p style='margin-top: 12px;'>Please Verify the following URL is a valid Redirect URL.</p> <a href= " + redirURL + "' target='_blank'>" + redirURL + "</a><p style='margin-top: 8px;'> By clicking verify you are confirming this is a valid URL and will proceed with checkout. </p>";
```

I would like the link to add http:// if the variable redirURL is missing it.  I am a little lost on how i would do it.

thank you

Answer (score 7):

So how about:

```
if(redirURL.IndexOf('http') !== 0)
  redirURL = 'http://' + redirURL;
warningString = "<p style='margin-top: 12px;'>Please Verify the following URL is a valid Redirect URL.</p> <a href= " + redirURL + "' target='_blank'>" + redirURL + "</a><p style='margin-top: 8px;'> By clicking verify you are confirming this is a valid URL and will proceed with checkout. </p>";
```

Comment: `< 0` may not be the best solution (`www.httpd.com`). Try `!== 0`.

Comment: It doesn't matter since `indexOf` will never return `""`

Comment: true, im in the habit of === now, so i often don't apply common sense

Comment: fwiw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use